# React: Make footer sit at the bottom

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make my footer sit at the bottom but I am not able to. This is what I am currently getting.

[image]

Following is my footer css:

```
.footer-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    padding: 15px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Following is my Footer HTML:

```
<div className="footer-container">
                   <div className="footer-item">© 2021 Overland Ninja. All rights reserved.</div> 
</div>
```

Any help on how to achieve this would be much appreciated!

Comment: try using the <footer></footer> tag?

Comment: Nope, Doesn't work

Comment: `position:fixed` ?

Comment: try: position: fixed; and bottom: 0px;

Comment: I dont want it to be fixed. I just want it at the bottom

Comment: You might want to open the DevTools in your browser-of-choice and find out if the `<body>` covers the whole browser window height.

Answer (score 1):

```
position: fixed
```

should work. Try it.

Comment: No its not -- please open the image in a new tab -- You will see what I am talking about

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

try use flexbox as example:

```
    <body>
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
      <footer class="footer"></footer>
    </body>
```

```
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .content {
      flex: 1 0 auto;
    }
    .footer {
      flex-shrink: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    /*This will make your page stretch to the full height of the screen if it's not.*/
}

.footer-container{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px; left: 0px;
    /*This will position your footer always at the bottom of the page*/
}
```

Maybe this will help. For this to work properly the footer-container has to be a "direct" child of body.